# Import Multiple csv files and write the string "End" in every .csv file

Tags: powershell, csv

I have multiple .csv files in one of the directory. Please find one .csv file below as a reference.

```
Tag,Timestamp,value
R,25-Feb-19 00:00:10, 50
R,25-Feb-19 00:00:20, 60
R,25-Feb-19 00:00:30, 65
```

The output is that it should add a string letter (`"End"`) using windows powershell. Please find the below example as output of one .csv file

```
Tag,Timestamp,value
R,25-Feb-19 00:00:10, 50
R,25-Feb-19 00:00:20, 60
R,25-Feb-19 00:00:30, 65
End
```

This should happen to all of .csv files in the directory using Windows Powershell 
I am very new to windows powershell. can any one of you help me on this ?

Comment: Welcome as a new user to SO. Please take the [tour] and also read [ASK]. [SO] isn't a free script writing service. Own research and code attempts are expected. [Edit] the question to include **your** code in a [mcve]. Try `Get-ChildItem *.csv | Add-Content -value 'END'`

Comment: By appending the word `End`, the CSV file becomes invalid because that line will have just one column instead of three.. Pease explain what the purpose of this is.